# threejs loading animated object cannot decode

Tags: three.js

hey guys i am new to threejs and i am trying to import this animated dinosaur that i have downloaded online from. i am trying to load and import and run in my web but met some errors. for file structure, the material_diffuse.png and material_specularGlossiness.png and scene.gltf and scene.bin are all in the same folder as index.html.

some of the errors i face are listed.

```
textures/Material_diffuse.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

textures/Material_specularGlossiness.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

GLTFLoader.js:127 DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.
```

this is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>3d model</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      canvas {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      import { GLTFLoader } from "./GLTFLoader.js";

      var scene = new THREE.Scene();

      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.01,
        1000
      );
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      var loader = new GLTFLoader();

      var obj;
      loader.load("scene.gltf", function (gltf) {
        obj = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
      });
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
      scene.add(light);
      // camera.position.set(0, 5, 30);
      camera.position.set(0, 5, 8);

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      animate(); 

      function rotateFunction() {
        obj.rotation.y += 0.01;
      }

     document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { rotateFunction() });
    </script>
    <div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reported errors, the file structure should look like so:

```
+-- scene.gltf
+-- scene.bin
+-- textures
|   +-- Material_diffuse.png
|   +-- Material_specularGlossiness.png
```

Meaning you have to put your textures into a `textures` directory.

Besides, the imports of your app are wrong. Use these imports for now until your app works:

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0/build/three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

Comment: hey man thanks, it solved the first few errors, currently there's this error , which says server responsed with 404, i tried refreshing it but didnt work.     GLTFLoader%20.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Please load the files from the CDN and remove all other imports. Meaning remove `<script src="three.js"></script>` and `<script type="module" src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>`.

Comment: i did and now the error is GET https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/three@v0.135.0-pjGUcRG9Xt70OdXl97VF/dist=es2019,mode=raw/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader%20.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 , any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, there was a space in the URL of `GLTFLoader`. I have updated the code, please try it again.

Comment: oh, i managed to fix that but now it says the textures arent loaded but i have placed them in the textures folder, do i need to load the textures in the code? three.js:24061 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/textures/Material_diffuse.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: No you have not. `GLTFLoader` loads textures automatically. It will be probably easier to fix the remaining issue if you share your entire code + assets as a GitHub repo.